# Should a variable name be changed if its purpose changes?

Tags: programming-practices

I'll change my personal code often and not worry about going back and changing the associated variable names.

Should variable names be maintained in case of meaning changes?

```
var accountCurrentValue = x;
var accountYesterdayValue = y;
var accountValueChange = accountCurrentValue - accountYesterdayValue;
```

--> `accountPastValue` becomes instead the previous month's value

```
var accountCurrentValue = x;
var accountLastMonthValue = y;
var accountValueChange = accountCurrentValue - accountLastMonthValue;
```

Comment: Many modern IDEs can perform refactoring across the entire project if necessary to rename something. Use this feature if you have it!

Answer (score 4):

Code is written to be executed by machine, but to be *read* by humans. The latter case is more important.

By all means keep identifiers in the code as accurately reflecting their purpose as possible.

Where I now am, a typical and legit kind of code review complaint is 'please rename this variable / function to be more descriptive'.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely yes, change variable names when relevant (especially variables whose scope is bigger than what fits in a screen). The name of a variable is an important part of its documentation!

Computers (e.g. compilers) don't care about variable names. You could name all your variables like `x01`, `x02` etc..., and the compiler nearly won't notice and the binary program would behave like before. But humans don't grasp these!

[Source code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) is -by definition- read and improved by humans. It is the prefered form for human developers to work on software (this is why naming and comments are important).